# Character-based Text Classification with Triplet Loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

Im trying to implement a text-classifier using *triplet loss* to classify different job descriptions into categories based on this [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W16-1617.pdf). But whatever i do, the classifier yields very bad results.

For the embedding i followed this [tutorial](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/lstm-with-char-embeddings-for-ner/) and the NN architecture is based on this [article](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W16-1617.pdf).

I create my encodings using:

```
max_char_len = 20
group_numbers = range(0, len(job_groups))
char_vocabulary = {'PAD':0}
X_char = []
y_temp = []
i = 1
for group, number in zip(job_groups, group_numbers):
   for job in group:
      job_cleaned = some_cleaning_function(job)
      job_enc = []
      for c in job_cleaned:
         if c in char_vocabulary.keys():
            job_enc.append(char_vocabulary[c])
         else:
            char_vocabulary[c] = i
            job_enc.append(char_vocabulary[c])
            i+=1
      X_char.append(job_enc)
      y_temp.append(number)
X_char = pad_sequences(X_char, maxlen = max_char_length, truncating='post')
```

My Neural Network is set up the following way:

```
def create_base_model():
  char_in = Input(shape=(max_char_length,), name='Char_Input')
  char_enc = Embedding(input_dim=len(char_vocabulary)+1, output_dim=20, mask_zero=True,name='Char_Embedding')(char_in)
  x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.4))(char_enc)
  x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.4))(x)
  x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.4))(x)
  x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.4))(x)
  out = Dense(128, activation = "softmax")(x)
  return Model(char_in, out)

def get_siamese_triplet_char():
  anchor_input_c = Input(shape=(max_char_length,),name='Char_Input_Anchor')
  pos_input_c = Input(shape=(max_char_length,),name='Char_Input_Positive')
  neg_input_c = Input(shape=(max_char_length,),name='Char_Input_Negative')

  base_model = create_base_model(encoding_generator)
  encoded_anchor = base_model(anchor_input_c)
  encoded_positive = base_model(pos_input_c)
  encoded_negative = base_model(neg_input_c)

  inputs = [anchor_input_c, pos_input_c, neg_input_c]
  outputs = [encoded_anchor, encoded_positive, encoded_negative]

  siamese_triplet = Model(inputs, outputs)
  siamese_triplet.add_loss((triplet_loss(outputs)))

  siamese_triplet.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam')
  return siamese_triplet, base_model
```

The triplet loss is defined as follows:

```
def triplet_loss(inputs):
   anchor, positive, negative = inputs
   positive_distance = K.square(anchor - positive)
   negative_distance = K.square(anchor - negative)
   positive_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(positive_distance, axis=-1, keepdims = True))
   negative_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(negative_distance, axis=-1, keepdims = True))
   loss = positive_distance - negative_distance
   loss = K.maximum(0.0, 1 + loss)
   return K.mean(loss)
```

The model is then trained with:

```
    siamese_triplet_char.fit(x=
              [Anchor_chars_train, 
               Positive_chars_train, 
               Negative_chars_train],
              shuffle=True, batch_size=8, epochs=22, verbose=1)
```

**My goal is to**: First, train the network with no label data in order to minimize the space of the different phrases and second, add a classification layer and create the final classifier.

My **general problem** is that even the first phase shows sinking cost-values it **overfits** and the validation results jump around and the second phase fails badly as I'm not able to train the model to actually classify.

My questions are the following:

1. Could someone explain the Embedding Architecture? What is the output dimension refering to? The individual characters? Would that even make sense? Or is there a better way to encode the input data?
2. How can i add `validation_data` to a network that does not contain labeled data? I could use `validation_split`, but i would rather prefer passing specific data to validate as my data is stratified.
3. Is there a reason why the classification does not work? Applying a simple K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm achieves at best 0.5 accuracy! Is it because of the data? Or is there a systematic error in my system?

All ideas and suggestions are really appreciated!